# Prestashop 1.6.0.9 with php 5.6

Tags: php, apache, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to configure php5.6 for prestashop 1.6.0.9 but I do not understand which functions are not supported.
Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to their [official documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/What+you+need+to+get+started), PrestaShop 1.6 works with PHP 5.2 or later, so you shouldn't have problems with PHP 5.6.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your return but it just does not work in 5.6 I have errors.
That's why I was wondering what version of php the prestashop 1.6.0.9 was functional